# How can I auto-hide/open panels in Unity with multiple buttons?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, menu, panel

I have tried to find solutions but somehow I can't find the right solution for my problem. I have 5 buttons and each button opens or closes its panel. However, I want that if I click on Button 2 that the panel closes for Button 1 and so. There should be only one panel active for each button.

It is just having a tab menu you are clicking through, only the panel of the last pressed button is active. I have seen a tutorial with images and Eventsystems but does not fit my current project.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the "Toggle Group" component in Unity:  https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ToggleGroup.html.  It will do what you're looking for -- group together a set of toggles so that only 1 can be active at any time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have never thought about a Toggle Group. I have never used it so far, but will definitely have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list for panels and in the same order add buttons to the another list. Respective button and panel in same places. Then when you press a button get index it in script. Activate matching panel index and disable others. In my script, I don't want to disable panels because I need to those script to run everytime. In your case you can just disable them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < panels.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
            {
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = true;
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;

                // Place to front for interaction
                panels[i].transform.SetAsLastSibling();
            }
            else
            {
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = false;
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0;
                panels[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this. I hope I will be able to implement it. If I understood it correctly, I run this piece of code in each button which is going to have the same script. So, when I click the button the index is checked and according to it the canvas changes.

Comment: Exactly. But , as I said, I used **CanvasGroup** in my project that's why there is CanvasGroup in my code. If you just want to disable panel object, use **panel.gameObject.SetActive(false)**

Comment: Thank you very much. As soon as I can I will test it out.